# How to get the environment variables in the hook script of the golang-buildpack in Heroku?

Tags: database, go, automation, buildpack

I have met a very odd issue, when I was building the script of the automation for the DB migration. I followed the official document:

> Pre/Post Compile Hooks
>
> If the file bin/go-pre-compile or bin/go-post-compile exists and is executable then it will be executed either before compilation (go-pre-compile) of the repo, or after compilation (go-post-compile).
>
> Because the buildpack installs compiled executables to bin, the go-post-compile hook can be written in go if it's installed by the specified  (see above).

Then I crafted the `go-post-compile` script below:

```
var (
    appURI := os.Getenv("APP_URI")
    databaseURL := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("app_uri: %s\n", appURI)
    fmt.Printf("database_url: %s\n", databaseURL)
    sourcePath := fmt.Sprintf("file://%s/db/migrations", appURI)
    m, err := migrate.New(sourcePath, databaseURL)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Failed to establish the connection of the migration.", err)
    }
    err = m.Up()
    if err != nil && err.Error() == "no change" {
        fmt.Println("  > NOTE: There is no change related to the operation of the migration.")
        return
    } else if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Failed to establish the connection of the migration.", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("  > Done.")
}
```

When I pushed the code to the heroku, I got the following error:

```
remote: -----> Running bin/go-post-compile hook
remote: app_uri: 
remote: database_url: ?sslmode=require
remote: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
remote: [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x58 pc=0x503b06]
remote:
```

It seems that the process could not get the environment variables when it run the `go-post-compile` script.

The process works well with the config vars after the buildpack compiles the application.

So do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I found the solution about running the automation of the DB migration. Developers should run these kinds of commands in the `release phase` in Heroku. You can check the official document: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase